# Empty test handling

Tags: bash, shell-script, arguments, test

Am learning bash and it's confusing how (why) this line of code `if [$1 = ]; then` works. Can someone please explain.

From bash tuturial [here](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-12.html) under **File re-namer** (6th block)

```
# a quick check to see if any files were given
# if none then it's better not to do anything than rename some non-existent
# files!!

if [$1 = ]; then
    echo "no files given"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Stop referring the TLDP documentation - Follow this [The Bash Wiki hackers](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is wrong, it does not work if the argument is not empty (and does not begin with whitespace) because `[` is not a special character and is not recognised as command if it is not a separate word (that would not even work with `[[`).

`set -x` shows you what the shell sees:

```
set -x
[$1 = ]
    + '[' = ']'
```

In that case the test result is true because there is a string between `[` and `]`; it does not matter that it is `=`.

Tests for a non-empty argument should be done as

```
[ -n "$1" ] ; echo $?
    + '[' -n '' ']'
    + echo 1
```

or

```
[ -z "$1" ] ; echo $?
    + '[' -z '' ']'
    + echo 0
```

instead

Comment: @spaceout `[[` is bash-specific, `[` is POSIX so if you do not need `[[` (which is more powerful) then you should stick to `[`.

Comment: or using an old hack, "x"$1 = "x"