# How do I check the result of a command for an output vs no output in zsh if statement?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, zsh, diff

I would like to compare 2 files using `diff` and then if it returns nothing then `echo "no diff"` else display the difference. My current if statement only works if there is no difference but if there is then it gives me a "not found" error.

This is what the test.sh looks like:

```bsh
#!/bin/zsh
if [$(diff file1 file2) = '']
then
    echo "no diff"
else
    diff file1 file2
fi
```

If files are same:

```bsh
$ sh test.sh
no diff
```

If files are different:

```bsh
$ cat file1
hello

$ cat file2
goodbye

$ sh test.sh
test.sh: 1: test.sh: [1,8c1,8: not found
< hello
---
> goodbye
```

In my search to find solutions, I found that having spaces `if [ $(diff` vs `if [$(diff` made a difference and using a single `=` vs `==` also helped. I figured the problem must be that I'm testing the output for `''` (nothing). It actually does work but the "not found" line doesn't belong there. I don't just want to silence that annoying line but do the if statement the proper way because there should be a way to get the result I need without having to run the `diff` twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`diff` provides an exit status of zero if no differences were found, so just use `diff` once and output message if required:

```
if diff file1 file2; then
    echo 'no diff'
fi
```

---

- `diff` utility may have the option `-s`/`--report-identical-files` (an extension to the POSIX specification). This would simplify the command to:

  ```
  diff -s file1 file2
  ```
- Reason for error `[1,8c1,8: not found` was bad syntax: `[` needs to appear on its own with a valid expression, and a closing `]` argument. Info about how to use `test` can be found here on unix.stackexchange ([link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146942/396144) [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/420092/396144) [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/435458/396144)) & in manual pages `man 1 test` & `man 1p test`
- In `test.sh`, the first line is `#!/bin/zsh`, but then the script is being run with `sh` interpreter (which probably isn't `zsh`). If you do want to use `zsh` features, then you'll want to make sure that you are actually running the script with `zsh`

Comment: Yes, that gives me a better result! I'm still getting `1,8c1,8` as part of the output. How can I get rid of that? EDIT: Wait, I see that's from `diff` itself and the `-s` option is actually what I needed. Thanks.